# nervous to be standing up here vs nervous standing up here

Tags: meaning

> I'm so nervous to be standing up here.
>
> I'm so nervous standing up here.

Is there any difference between these two sentences or do they imply the same thing and you can simply omit the 'to be' part? 
Just in case the context is where you're standing in front of a lot of people and you're nervous!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to depend on exactly what adjective is involved. We nearly always include the infinitive in, say, *I'm so **excited to be** standing up here*, but *I'm so **exposed** standing up here* sounds much more likely with no infinitive. In fact, I can't actually imagine a context where someone might say *I'm so **exposed to be** standing up here*. With ***nervous*** I find both forms acceptable, but I'd lean towards ***not*** including ***to be*** - especially if I replace ***I'm*** with ***I feel...*** (which also works fine with ***excited***).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend on the context—and more than just what has been described. Normally, the two sentences would be interpreted in the same way.

However, let's say it's a seasoned magician who's about to perform a new and difficult trick, and who has just walked onto a stage in front of an audience. Looking at the literal words in the two sentences, they could be interpreted in this way:

> I'm so nervous to be standing up here.

This could mean that they are nervous *because* they are standing there. It's unlikely that a performer who stands on a stage in front of a crowd on a regular basis would say this.

> I'm so nervous standing up here.

This could simply mean that they are nervous *as* they are standing there. The source of their nervousness might not be because they are standing there (and, in this case, it likely isn't), but because of the new act they are about to perform.

---

So, generally speaking, the two sentences mean the same thing. (And either may or may not indicate the standing there as the *source* of the nervousness.) But in some contexts, the first sentence more directly indicates the standing there as the cause of the nervousness.